# Applying advanced logic to modify a list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists

```
copy_from = ['2.02,1.91', '1.9,2.06', '1.86,1.98']
copy_to = [('-0.25', '2.02,1.91'), ('-1.50', '1.9,2.06')]
```

The net result should be:

```
fixed = [('-0.25', '2.02,1.91', '2.02,1.91'), ('-1.50', '1.9,2.06', '1.86,1.98')]
```

All I want to do is take 2nd item from each tuple (list `copy_to`) eg. `'2.02,1.91'` and  check its location within list `copy_from`. Once we have localized it, I want to take the next item from list `copy_from` (`'1.9,2.06'`) and copy it back to the approperiate tuple in list `copy_to`. BUT, `copy_from` is sometimes missing the approperiate *next* item. This is when `copy_to'` tuple items are neighbours within `copy_from`. And in the above they are.

When this is the case I must not take the *next* item, I have to duplicate *the item* instead (as shown in `fixed` 1st tuple). If there were no neighbours, like this:

```
copy_from = ['2.02,1.91', '2, 1.89', '1.9,2.06', '1.86,1.98']
copy_to = [('-0.25', '2.02,1.91'), ('-1.50', '1.9,2.06')]
```

then the result should be:

```
fixed = [('-0.25', '2.02,1.91', '2, 1.89'), ('-1.50', '1.9,2.06', '1.86,1.98')]
```

There will be both - neighbouring and not neighbouring items.

I'm aware the explanation got confusing quite a bit, hope you can understand where I'm coming from. I know, this is a complex task, so any hints like where to look, which library may be useful welcome as well!

Comment: What is the actual task? And if you can give a textual description of the algorithm you want to execute, why can't you just code it?

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't make any sense... Why does the first `fixed` repeat `'2.02,1.91'`?  And why doesn't the second like you say it should?  In addition to what @Marcin said, maybe a better description of the larger problem you're solving... strings of numbers sounds like a bad plan to me.

Comment: What does "missing the appropriate **next** item" mean? Also it seems that you've italicized random words, which really doesn't help explaining.

Comment: The input stream you are trying to handle is formatted in a brittle manner -- correctly identifying tuples that are missing their neighbor will require multiple recursive attempts to fit schema to stream. (Consider `copy_from = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')` and `copy_to = [('a', '1'), ('b', 2'), ('c', '3'), ('d', '4')]`.) The best solution here is to handle your input stream in a different manner so that this problem is not intractable.

Comment: Your input is a nightmare.  Just because you _can_ handle lists of tuples of floating-point strings doesn't mean you _should_.  Chances are you should be using a `dict` somewhere, probably more than one place.

Comment: @roippi I know it is, I'm scraping a site which is a mess. Thanks llb, I hoped I could go without recursion ;/

Comment: @nutship How are you scraping the site? The correct solution here is almost certainly to change your scraping strategy to give different output, since you appear to be losing vital context and then attempting to reconstruct it afterwards.

Comment: This is such a messy string which I can only bite with regex. I've tries a lot of different approaches. I'm left with this one.

Comment: @nutship This is definitely not the right one. The fact that most of the people reading your question cannot understand what your algorithm is supposed to be is a hint that it is not a workable solution. What is the regex you are doing?

Comment: I bet my regex was correct. It is more about expressing myself in english rightly. Anyways, is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
>>> result=[]
>>> copy_from_max_idx = len(copy_from) -1
>>> copy_to_max_idx = len(copy_to)-1
>>> for i,e in enumerate(copy_to):
    try:
        idx = copy_from.index(e[1])
    except:
        idx = -1
    if idx >=0:
        #check neighbours (next item actually)
        next_copy_from = e[1] if idx >= copy_from_max_idx else copy_from[idx + 1]
        next_copy_to = '' if i >= copy_to_max_idx else copy_to[i+1][1]
        if next_copy_to == next_copy_from:
            result.append(e + (e[1],))
        else:
            result.append(e + (next_copy_from,))
```

Comment: Note that it is not actually checking neighbours, just the next item. Can be modified to do that; but I am too lazy to do this right now :p; sorry...

Comment: Thank you anyways. I check against some more lists and it seems to be working correctly.

Comment: I find this solution complex and also it uses try/except which is slower.

Comment: wow, it breaks under this inputs `copy_from = ['1.74,2.25', '1.78,2.2', '1.94,2']` and
`copy_to = [('-1.50', '1.74,2.25'), ('-1.75', '1.94,2')]`,  `next_copy_from = copy_from[idx + 1]
IndexError: list index out of range` .When it tries to look for **next** item and there is none. Any chance you can tweak this?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty confusing, and confused. But I think whatever your actual problem is, your first step should be to create a `dict`. When your problem is "I need to look up a key and get the corresponding value, or get some default value if it's not present", the answer is usually `dict.get`.

For example, you could create a `dict` mapping each member of `copy_from` to its succeeding member:

```
copy_from = ['2.02,1.91', '1.9,2.06', '1.86,1.98']
dict_from = dict(zip(copy_from, copy_from[1:]))
```

Now, to get the next value for any value in `copy_from`, or the key itself if not present:

```
value = dict_from.get(value, value)
```

In particular:

```
>>> v = '1.9,2.06'
>>> dict_from.get(v, v)
'1.86,1.98'
>>> v = '1.86,1.98'
>>> dict_from.get(v, v)
'1.86,1.98'
```

I *think* that's at least on the road to what you want?

Comment: You're a brave soul for trying to interpret that question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a whole lotta bad... but I think this does what you're looking for... but clean your input instead as per all the comments!

```
copy_from = ['2.02,1.91', '1.9,2.06', '1.86,1.98']
copy_to = [('-0.25', '2.02,1.91'), ('-1.50', '1.9,2.06')]

fixed = []
for ct in copy_to:
    if ct[1] in copy_from:
        idx = copy_from.index(ct[1])
        if idx < len(copy_from):
            ct += (copy_from[idx+1], )
        else:
            ct += (copy_from[idx], )
    fixed.append(ct)
```

Comment: I would suggest explicitly comparing `idx` and `len(copy_from)` instead of the try except.

Comment: This won't work for the example case in the OP. Compare your function's output to `fixed`.

Comment: @llb correct, but the OP's words don't match the outputs... so I matched his words...  and updated to compare to `len(copy_from)`

Comment: Hi Justin, it's close to what I'm looking for but the output should be `fixed = [('-0.25', '2.02,1.91', '2.02,1.91'), ('-1.50', '1.9,2.06', '1.86,1.98')]` not `[('-0.25', '2.02,1.91', '1.9,2.06'), ('-1.50', '1.9,2.06', '1.86,1.98')]`. Take items from `copy_to`  `'2.02,1.91'`, `'1.9,2.06'`. Compare them against `copy_from`, if they are immediatelly one after another I can't take the `next` item.

Comment: That was wholly unclear to me from your question... if thats the case, the `enumerate` solution from @mshsayem is probably your best bet... but find a better way to structure your data instead!

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the effort. Expressing myself in english trouble me sometimes :)

Answer (score 1):

First to destination list is a list of tuples, an tuples are immutable, so I had to do a tricky conversion to a list of lists.

This is what I came up with:

```
def doStuff(ref, dest):

    tmp = [list(x) for x in dest]
    search_keys  = [l[1] for l in tmp]

    ref_pairs  = [ref[n:n+2] for n in range(0, len(ref), 1) if len(ref[n:n+2]) > 1]
    dest_pairs = [search_keys[n:n+2] for n in range(0, len(search_keys), 1)]


    for index,pair in enumerate(dest_pairs):

        if pair in ref_pairs:
            tmp[index].append(pair[0])
        else:
            candidate_pair = [p for p in ref_pairs if p[0] == pair[0]]

            if candidate_pair:
                tmp[index].append(candidate_pair[0][1])
            else:
                tmp[index].append(None)

    return [tuple(l) for l in tmp]

# Test case 1
copy_from = ['2.02,1.91', '1.9,2.06', '1.86,1.98']
copy_to   = [('-0.25', '2.02,1.91'), ('-1.50', '1.9,2.06')]

copy_to = doStuff(copy_from, copy_to)
print 'Case1:\n', copy_to

# Test case 2
copy_from = ['2.02,1.91', '2, 1.89', '1.9,2.06', '1.86,1.98']
copy_to = [('-0.25', '2.02,1.91'), ('-1.50', '1.9,2.06')]

copy_to = doStuff(copy_from, copy_to)
print 'Case2:\n',  copy_to

# Test case 3
copy_from = ['2.02,1.91', '2, 1.89', '1.9,2.06']
copy_to = [('-0.25', '2.02,1.91'), ('-1.50', '1.9,2.06')]

copy_to = doStuff(copy_from, copy_to)
print 'Case3:\n',  copy_to
```

Output of the 3 test cases:

```
Case1:
[('-0.25', '2.02,1.91', '2.02,1.91'), ('-1.50', '1.9,2.06', '1.86,1.98')]
Case2:
[('-0.25', '2.02,1.91', '2, 1.89'), ('-1.50', '1.9,2.06', '1.86,1.98')]
Case3:
[('-0.25', '2.02,1.91', '2, 1.89'), ('-1.50', '1.9,2.06', None)]
```

Comment: Your solution is nice indeed but not sure why it would not output `[('-0.25', '2.02,1.91', '2.02,1.91'), ('-1.50', '1.9,2.06', '1.86,1.98')]` for the case one. Your case one output is not correct.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't see that line where you explain this. Solved.

Comment: Please try with more of your test cases, to see if anything breaks in my code, if not, perfect.